# Python Selenium Click Interception error from a random popup

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hello I am using a automated web scraper but at random times the screen is covered with an accept cookies popup that blocks the form click button. It affects the whole script and I don't know how I could write and if cookie_pop_up.close() or something of that nature. Get the xpath of the close  for cookies?

I am trying to log into snapchat here is my code:

```
hrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                chrome_options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server=http://{random.choice(live_proxies)}")
                driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
                driver.set_window_position(-10000,0)
                driver.get("https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/login")
                if "Log in to Snapchat" in driver.page_source:
                    proxy_is_valid = True
                    user_input = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
                    user_input.send_keys(user)

                    passsword_input = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
                    passsword_input.send_keys(password)

                    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button")
                    login_button.click()
                    if check_for_captcha_connectivity(driver):

                        solve(driver)
```

Here is the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">...</button> is not clickable at point (507, 384). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cookie-popup">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
```

HERE IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE THAT BLOCKS IT FROM LOGIN:
https://imgur.com/gallery/sZroFq9

thanks in advance!

update I tried this

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button")
                    login_button.click()
                    if ElementClickInterceptedException:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]").click()
                        continue
```

still failed the indents pasted weirdly ^

Comment: you can use execute_script to click on items using javascript/jquery that will not be affected with pop-ups

Comment: Your code could see if there's a `div class="cookie-popup"` and if exists, close it, if it doesn't keep running the rest of your code

Comment: Can you share the link of the webpage ?

Comment: @JuanC I just tried that

Answer (score 1):

You need to agree to the cookies consent first and then proceed. To accept the cookie consent you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cookie-popup"))).click()
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cookie-popup']"))).click()
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I added this code before it clicks the submit button but now it seems to just stop and not even close the cookies. Do you have discord where I can send you my code sir, I'll pay a bit if you can fix this issue.

Comment: @DanC Can you update the question with some more details  and update me please?

Comment: I added a image of what's stopping and causing the error I think and the code I am using to simulate a login